# Parsing data coming from a URL

Tags: java, performance, parsing, hash-map, url

I need to parse the data coming from a URL:

```
haschanged=true
version=1
timestamp=1389562122310
DATACENTER=/pr/hello/plc
    TotalNumberOfServers:4
    primary:{0=1, 1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=1, 11=2, 12=1, 13=2}
    secondary:{0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=0, 9=0, 10=0, 11=1, 12=0, 13=0}
    hosttomachine:{3=plcdbx1115.plc.domain.com, 2=plcdbx1114.plc.domain.com, 1=plcdbx1113.plc.domain.com, 4=plcdbx1116.plc.domain.com}
DATACENTER=/pr/hello/pty
    TotalNumberOfServers:2
    primary:{0=1, 1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=1, 11=2, 12=1, 13=2, 14=1}
    secondary:{0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=0, 9=0, 10=0, 11=1, 12=0, 13=0, 14=0}
    hosttomachine:{1=ptydbx1145.pty.domain.com, 4=ptydbx1148.pty.domain.com}
DATACENTER=/pr/hello/vgs
    TotalNumberOfServers:0
    primary:{}
    secondary:{}
    hosttomachine:{}
```

After parsing the data I need to store all datacenter data in a `Map` like this:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryData
```

For example, the Key of `primaryData` is `/pr/hello/plc` and value is:

```
{0=1, 1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=1, 11=2, 12=1, 13=2}
```

which is for primary.

Similarly another `Map` for secondary for each datacenter:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryData
```

For example, the Key of `secondaryData` is `/pr/hello/plc` and value is:

```
{0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=0, 9=0, 10=0, 11=1, 12=0, 13=0}
```

which is for secondary.

And lastly, one more map for hosttomachine mapping for each datacenter:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> hostMachineMapping -
```

For example, the key of `hostMachineMapping` is `/pr/hello/plc` and value is:

```
{3=plcdbx1115.plc.domain.com, 2=plcdbx1114.plc.domain.com, 1=plcdbx1113.plc.domain.com, 4=plcdbx1116.plc.domain.com}
```

which is for hosttomachine.

And all the above map will have data for its datacenter as I have three datacenter in the above example. So each each map will have three data. And also I will parse the above response only when `haschanged` is equal to `true`. If it is not true, then I won't parse anything.

Here is the code I have so far, but it takes more than 200 ms to parse the data and store it in its corresponding hashmap. Is there any way to parse the above data efficiently and store it in a particular `ConcurrentHashMap`?

```
private void parseResponse(String response) throws Exception {
    if (response != null) {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryData = null;
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryData = null;
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> hostMachineMapping = null;

        long version = -1;
        long timestamp = 0L;
        boolean changed = false;
        String splitResponse[] = response.split("DATACENTER=");

        boolean flag = false;
        for (String sr : splitResponse) {
            if (!flag) {
                flag = true;
                String[] header = sr.split("\n");
                changed = Boolean.parseBoolean(header[0].split("=")[1]);
                if (!changed) {
                return;
                } else {
                version = Integer.parseInt(header[1].split("=")[1]);
                timestamp = Long.parseLong(header[2].split("=")[1]);
                primaryData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
                secondaryData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
                hostMachineMapping = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
                }

            } else {
                generateDATACENTERMap(sr, primaryData, secondaryData, hostMachineMapping);
            }
        }

        if (changed) {
            Mapping.setPrimaryData(primaryData);
            Mapping.setSecondaryData(secondaryData);
            Mapping.setHostMachineMapping(hostMachineMapping);
            Mapping.setTimestamp(timestamp);
            Mapping.setVersion(version);
        }
    }
}

private void generateColoMap(String sr, ConcurrentMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryData,
ConcurrentMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryData,
ConcurrentMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> hostMachineMapping) throws Exception {

String[] data = sr.split("\n\t");
String dcName = data[0];
int numOfServers = Integer.parseInt(data[1].split(":")[1]);

    if (numOfServers > 0) {
        primaryData.put(dcName, generateMap(data[2]));
        secondaryData.put(dcName, generateMap(data[3]));
        hostMachineMapping.put(dcName, generateMap(data[4]));
    }
}

private ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> generateMap(String map) throws Exception {

String tableString = map.split(":")[1];
ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> table = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
tableString = tableString.substring(1, tableString.length() - 1);
String[] entries = tableString.split(", ");

    for (String e : entries) {
        String[] entryVal = e.split("=");
        table.put(Integer.parseInt(entryVal[0]), entryVal[1]);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex to the rescue

- Regex for key: `(?<=DATACENTER=).*`
- Regex for primary values: `(?<=primary:\{).*(?=\})`
- Regex for secondary values: `(?<=secondary:\{).*(?=\})`
- Regex for hostMachine Mapping: `(?<=hosttomachine:\}).*(?=\})`
- Split on `","` for primary, secondary, and hostMachine

Use these as your patterns then go through each match. Each iteration should give you key with matching values.

Comment: I'm not *entirely* sure that regex is the best option here, but it seems like it's an option at least, so +1.